# When does UICollectionView ask for its data?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

When does `UICollectionView` asks for its data? If you add the `UICollectionView` in Interface Builder (storyboard) and then sets the `delegate` and `dataSource` property at the end of `viewDidLoad`. Does it automatically call `reloadData` inside the `dataSource` property or what?

Comment: What is your actual problem? Or is it only curiosity?

Answer (score 0):

you have to explicity call:

```
self.collectionView.reloadData()
```

once you model is ready.